# Button Actions for CLLocationManager(current location popup)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

I am having small struggle in finding current location, while using CLLocationManager it will ask for one notification like "Would you like to use your current location" right.. In that there two options named: 1.OK 2.Dont Allow.  Is it possible to write custom action for this two buttons... If anyone having any Idea to do this and related to this, then will be very useful for me..

Thank's in advance...

Answer (score 0):

make method like this and attach it to your button or call it from viewDidLoad

```
-(void) showLocation
{
  // put an alerview to ask user for allow/disallow
}
```

// in alerView delegate methods, agains yes button enable user current location

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can override the actions for this alert. However, you can implement CLLocationManager's delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

In there you can find out whether the user has enabled or not the location services for your app.

Here's an example of an implementation for the above method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    switch([error code]) {
        case kCLErrorDenied:
            //User has not enabled location services for this app.
            break;
        case kCLErrorLocationUnknown:
            //location could not be found
            break;
        default:
            //some other issue
            break;
    }

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An error title"
                                                    message:@"An error message"
                                                    delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
```